# Typeorm nested relations for self referenced enitity

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have the following database structure: [2 table DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2syE0.png)

The questions table is linked with the answers table through `answers.questionId` references `questions.id`.

The self-referenced table is referenced through `answers.parentId` references `answers.id`.

For example, I have the following data:

Questions table:

[questions table entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niFch.png)

Answers table

[answers table entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9rpO.png)

Is it possible to get something like this (by querying with typeor):

```
[{id: 1, question: "What is my name?", answers: [{ value: "Man" }, { value: "Boss"}] },
 {id: 2, question: "Where I am?", answers: [*{ value: "Country", answers: [{ value: "Ro" }, { value: "En" }] }*, {value:"Iland"}]
```

I want to have the answers self-referenced relations as well.

I tried this:

```
 this.questionsRepo.find({
  relations: ['answers'],
});
```

But obviously I get only the question and answer array

Is it possible to do something like that with an orm like TypeOrm?

Thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to fix it. If somebody have similar issues, here is the code:

```
this.questionsRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('questions')
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
        'questions.answers',
        'answer',
        'answer.parentId is NULL',
      )
      .leftJoinAndSelect('answer.children', 'answer2')
      .getMany();
```